# Code applied to a pandas column - unable to even begin to decipher how it works

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following on a prewritten code which I understand for the most part but the below has me stumped.

```
columns = ['# over SMA']
apply_sum = dict([(x,'sum') for x in columns])
df= df.groupby(df.index).agg(apply_sum)
```

it looks like kind of iteration over the entries in column '# over SMA'.

Thanks

Comment: Can You share the dataframe with expected Output

Comment: thank you, but I was able to figure it out with the help of caleb courtney.

Answer (score 0):

I added documentation and re-wrote some of what it's doing for clarity, though (personally) I think the original line 2 was quite elegant.

```py
# columns you want to aggregate over
columns = ['# over SMA'] 

# rewritten for clarity
apply_sum = {}
for x in columns:
  apply_sum[x] = 'sum'

# groups along the index, then gets the sum of each column in the index
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(apply_sum)
```

Comment: thanks, I see your code has the same output as the original but I have a follow up question if you dont mind. apply_sum appears to be an empty dictionary and then there is a loop that iterates over column labeled '# over SMA'. I guess I dont understand how apply_sum[x] = 'sum' works. Thank you for any input

Comment: I figured it out, it seems like a very gimmicky solution given that the author could have used  df= df.groupby(df.index).agg(apply_sum) instead. Thanks for all your help